# Optimization allowed on volatile objects

Tags: c, optimization, language-lawyer, volatile

From *ISO/IEC 9899:201x* section *5.1.2.3 Program execution* paragraph *4*:

> In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by
>   the semantics. **An actual implementation need not evaluate part of an
>   expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no
>   needed side effects are produced** (**including any caused by** calling a
>   function or **accessing a volatile object**).

What exactly is the allowed optimization here regarding the volatile object? can someone give an example of a volatile access that **CAN** be optimized away?

Since volatiles access are an observable behaviour (described in paragraph *6*) it seems that no optimization can take please regarding volatiles, so, I'm curious to know what optimization is allowed in section *4*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can someone give an example of a volatile access that CAN be optimized
>   away?

I think that you misinterpreted the text, IMO this paragraph means that

```
volatile unsigned int bla = whatever();

if (bla < 0) // the code is not evaluated even if a volatile is involved
```

Comment: partially related- do you think this can be optimized away `volatile int x = 3; x;` ? the `x;` expression is fit for optimization?

Comment: And in this case you enter in undefined behaviour, (x is used uninitialized)

Comment: @KeineLust modified the comment

Comment: @StoryTeller can you explain why it should not be evaluated?

Comment: In this case I think x can not be otimized, see godbolt in this sample (compiled with O2, y is optimized but x is not): https://godbolt.org/z/08Q4Sb

Comment: @user2162550 - Short circuit evaluation is part of the abstract machine's execution models. Should be specified under the specification of logical AND.

Comment: @StoryTeller, oops, now I see what you mean about the shortcircuit, you are right, edited.

Comment: This is not a correct interpretation. The phrase “including…” modifies “side effects,” meaning that the side effects that could be needed include accessing a volatile object. If there is an access to a volatile object, it must be performed. The phrase would have been clearer if it had been written “no needed side effects (including any caused by calling a function or accessing a volatile object) are produced.”

Comment: Further, this answer is stating that in `if (bla < 0) SomeCodeHere;`, the `SomeCodeHere` does not need to be evaluated. That is true, but it is not what the quoted passage from the C standard is discussing. It is **not** what the passage means.

Comment: wait, I think there is a slight problem here. If a naive, conforming, compiler will evaluate `if (bla < 0)` then it will fetch `bla`'s value from memory (as it's volatile). Now, if other conforming compiler will not evaluate it, it will not fetch the volatile from memory, which will cause different observable behaviours (volatile access is observable behaviour) for the two conforming compilers which is not possible according to paragraph 6.

Answer (score 7):

Reformatting a little:

```
An actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if:

  a) it can deduce that its value is not used; and

  b) it can deduce that that no needed side effects are produced (including any
     caused by calling a function or accessing a volatile object).
```

Reversing the logic without changing the meaning:

```
An actual implementation must evaluate part of an expression if:

  a) it can't deduce that its value is not used; or

  b) it can't deduce that that no needed side effects are produced (including
      any caused by calling a function or accessing a volatile object).
```

Simplifying to focus on the volatile part:

```
An actual implementation must evaluate part of an expression if needed
side effects are produced (including accessing a volatile object).
```

Answer (score 3):

Accesses to volatile objects must be evaluated. The phrase “including any…” modifies “side effects.” It does not modify “if it can deduce…” It has the same meaning as:

> An actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no needed side effects (including any caused by calling a function or accessing a volatile object) are produced.

This means “side effects” includes side effects that are caused by accessing a volatile object. In order to decide it cannot evaluate part of an expression, an implementation must deduce that no needed side effects, including any caused by calling a function or accessing a volatile object, are produced.

It does not mean that an implementation can discard evaluation of part of an expression even if that expression includes accesses to a volatile object.

Comment: can you please add an example? i guess it's because i'm not an english native speaker, but i don't fully understand the answer

Comment: maybe: `int func() { int x = *volatile_ptr; return 0; }` so in this case accessing the volatile must be performed, but storing the value in `x` can be removed?

Comment: @user2162550: That is correct. In `int x = *volatile_ptr;`, `*volatile_ptr` has a side effect, which is to access the volatile object it points to. That side effect must be performed. Then `int x = *volatile_ptr;` nominally initializes `x`. But that initialization has no observable behavior. So it may be eliminated by optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another example that fits into this in my understanding:

```
volatile int vol_a;
....
int b = vol_a * 0; // vol_a is not evaluated
```

Comment: Just for the record, this is not duplicating the accepted answer as the latter is edited.

Comment: Idk, both gcc and clang on `-03` make a read on `a` if it is `volatile` https://godbolt.org/z/3tADBK . Although this is obviously not proof that they must act like this.

Comment: agree on the "must" part :)

Answer (score 0):

In cases where an access to a volatile object would affect system behavior in a way that would be necessary to make a program achieve its purpose, such an access must not be omitted.  If the access would have no effect whatsoever on system behavior, then the operation could be "performed" on the abstract machine without having to execute any instructions.  It would be rare, however, for a compiler writer to know with certainty that the effect of executing instructions to perform the accesses would be the same as the effect of pretending to do those instructions on the abstract machine while skipping them on the real one.

In the much more common scenario where a compiler writer would have no particular knowledge of any effect that a volatile access might have, but also have no particular reason to believe that such accesses *couldn't* have effects the compiler writer doesn't know about (e.g. because of hardware which is triggered by operations involving certain addresses), a compiler writer would have to allow for the possibility that such accesses might have "interesting" effects by performing them in the specified sequence, without regard for whether the compiler writer knows of any particular reason that the sequence of operations should matter.